# Getting `No such file or directory` error on egrep in function on zsh

Tags: grep, zsh

I've created a small function to allow me to grep through my command history on zsh. The command `history 1` will display the entire command history. And running `history 1 | egrep ls` shows just those command containing `ls`.

So my function looks like this:

```
h() {
  if [ -z "$*" ]
  then
    history 1
  else
    history 1 | egrep "$@"
  fi
}
```

Unfortunately this only results in the following error message:

```
$ h ls
egrep: ls: No such file or directory
```

I'm at a loss as to what is wrong in my script. I've trie both `grep` and `egrep` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've abandoned the function. Further reading on the subject of zsh history lead me to this very elegant solution that meets my needs. https://coderwall.com/p/jpj_6q

In a nutshell you add this to your .zshrc:

```
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-searc
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search # Up
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search # Down
```

Now your history can be searched by entering a partial term and using the up or down arrow keys to walk through the matches from your history file.

Answer (score 0):

What is the full path of `grep` or `egrep`?

It's possible that it's running in an alternate shell which has a different `PATH` set. Try using an explicit `/usr/bin/grep` or `/usr/bin/egrep` and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: `which egrep` and `which grep` result in `/usr/bin/egrep` and `/usr/bin/grep` respectively. Spelling out the full path to either in my function doesn't change the result. Still getting the "No such file of directory" error message.

Comment: If I add an additional argument to the input, such as `h ls 1`, I get `egrep: 1: No such file or directory`. Is it possible that you're passing additional information to the shell behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file history.zsh (slightly changed from the original):

```
#!/bin/zsh
h() {
  if [ -z "$*" ]
  then
    history
  else
    history | fgrep "$*"
  fi
}
```

Now source this file (so "h" will be refreshed):

```
. history.zsh
```

And call the new function:

```
$ h ls
30      h ls
31      ls
```

Comment: This answer would be great if it explained ***why*** the `1` was removed from `history 1`. And why you're using `fgrep` over `egrep`.

Comment: history 1 shows only the latest history item. I guess that you want to search all history. fgrep is more strict than grep and egrep and since you are looking for string it is enough (though grep and egrep should work too)

Comment: `history` by itself, e.g., with no `1` only shows the last 15 commands on my zsh installation. `history 1` causes the list to start with the first command. Changing to `fgrep` appears to have made no difference. You also changed the `"$@"` to `"$*"` for the `fgrep`. This eliminates the error message but I get no output at all. All of which makes me think the argument isn't getting passing correctly.